# parent element id

Tags: jquery, parent

can't get the parent id of the list the item is dragged into. I can get the items' id easily enough and thought i could get the parent from that but can't seem to grab it!

```
 <li id="tag_772" class="tag tagAssigned ui-draggable" >adventurous briefs</li>
```

is the li dragged in. Any help much appreciated!

```
$("li.tag").draggable({ 
        connectToSortable: 'ul.assignedClass',
        helper: 'clone',
        stop: function(event, ui) { 
            projectTags('add',$(this))
        }
    });

    function projectTags(fnc, tag){
        var tagID =  $(tag).attr("id")

        var parentID = $("#"+tagID).closest('ul').attr("id"); /// closest, parent & parents doesn't work?

        $("#fdbk").prepend("<li>fnc:"+fnc+", tag:"+tagID+" < "+ $("#"+tagID).parents("ul:first").attr("id")+"</li>");

    }
```

html;

```
<ul id="tags_978" class="assignedClass ui-sortable">

                <li id="existingTag_1029" class="tagAssigned">space </li>  


                <li id="existingTag_1030" class="tagAssigned">light </li>  


                <li id="existingTag_1031" class="tagAssigned">continuous landscape </li>  


                <li id="existingTag_1032" class="tagAssigned">structural glass </li>
<li id="tag_772" class="tag tagAssigned ui-draggable" >adventurous briefs</li>  



        </ul>
```

Comment: I'm confused. Did you mean to only have one draggable element? I'm trying to duplicate your code, and can't see to get any result.

Comment: you could change this: var tagID = $(tag).attr("id") to var tagID = tag.attr("id"); for efficiency

Comment: that's not the whole pages vose - just what i'm using to get the li id (and hopefully the parent ID)

working page; http://rd.modernactivity.co.uk/youradmin/tagManager.php

Comment: maybe you forgot 'existingTag_' prefix?

Comment: no - as tag_772 is the li that was dragged into the list. I can get that id easy. just don't understand why i can't get the parent frm that..

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:**

```
var parentID = $("#existingTag_"+tagID).parent('ul').attr("id");
```

try this;)

Comment: you forgot about tags_ prefix : $("#tag_"+tagID).parent('ul').attr("id");

Answer (score 1):

change the

```
var tagID =  $(tag).attr("id")
```

to

```
var tagID =  tag.attr("id");
```

This avoids the nested dom parse, and adds the semicolon on the end of the statement.
EDIT:for clarity and in addition:

```
var parentID = $('#'+tagID).parent('ul').attr('id');
```

Comment: still undefined - not sure what is going on!

Answer (score 0):

ok - gone the long way round...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var selectedList;

    $("#tagBrowser").resizable({
        grid: 20,

    });

    $("#tagBrowser").draggable({ 


    });

    $("ul.assignedClass").sortable({
        revert: true,
        items: 'li.tagAssigned', 
        stop: function(event, ui) { 

        },
       sort: function(event, ui) { 
       },
       change: function(event, ui) { 
            $("#fdbk").prepend("<li>change:"+$(this).attr("id")+" </li>");
            selectedList = $(this);
       }

    });

    $("li.tag").draggable({ 
        connectToSortable: 'ul.assignedClass',
        helper: 'clone',
        stop: function(event, ui) { 
            projectTags('add',$(this))
        }
    });


    function projectTags(fnc, tag){
        var tagID =  tag.attr("id");

        var parentID =  selectedList.attr("id"); /// closest, parent & parents doesn't work?

        $("#fdbk").prepend("<li>fnc:"+fnc+", tag:"+tagID+" < "+parentID+"</li>");

    }



});
```